# Attach django generated pdf in email

Tags: python, django, email-attachments

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on an Error.

When i try to send email with `generated pdf` then it is sending only the filename. BUT i am trying to send generated `pdf` in email

```
def send_pdf(request,pk):
    profiles = get_object_or_404(Profile,pk=pk)

    sent = False

    template_path = 'pdf2.html'
    context = {'profiles': profiles}
    # Create a Django response object, and specify content_type as pdf
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    # # if downlaod:
    # # response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"'

    # # if display:
    # response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="report.pdf"'

    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(context)

    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(
       html, dest=response)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DownloadDataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            subject = f"{request.user.username}'s Data"

            message = response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="report.pdf"'

            send_mail(subject,message,'yawanspace@gmail.com',
                [request.user.email])
            sent = True

    else:
        form = DownloadDataForm()

    context = {'sent':sent,'form':form}
    return render(request,'download_data.html', context)
```

I am trying to attach file which is in **message**. ( I don't want to read before send )

**What would be in the File ?**

The file will contain the data of the user like `Name and Email`.

I have no idea what i am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this function to attach pdf in your email

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
def send_email(subject, text_content, from_email, recepients):
    mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, recepients)
    file_path = "/usr/Downloads/my.pdf"
    file = open(file_path, "r+")
    attachment = file.read()
    file.close()
    mail.attach("my.pdf", attachment, "application/pdf")
    mail.send()
```

Moreover, you can refer from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects

Comment: BUT according to my `view` i am not saving 'pdf' in database. So how can i attach it with path ?

Comment: If you have data of that pdf in binary, then directly use it in attachment